# Magento import multiple product images with sort order

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, importerror

I am trying to import products using Magento 1.7 in built import/export dataflow profile function

So far I can import products details and multiple images as per [this tutorial](http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/6220/).

But problem here is I am not able to maintain store view and image sort order together.

How I can format CSV so that I can control image sort order and store view?

in short what is magento field name for image sort order?

( options tried but failed: position, image_position, media_gallery_position, gallery_position, gallery_position )

Scenario is:

We have three images per product out of which one image should have first sort order and store view thumbnail, small, base image active ie. this image should use as primary image of product and other two are just inner images only for  display purpose on product page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Magento importing exporting are always quirky problems. as far as I know for 1.7, there aren't much options.

http://devjuhong.com/web/magento-import-products-using-csv/
Check out above page it's pointing that problem too.

Comment: Can you summarize that link into your answer?

Answer (score 2):

[Store Manager for Magento](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/store-manager-for-magento-professional-edition-2.html) does a pretty good job at importing products. For say a 100 products it takes a minute or two which includes time for RE-INDEXING product data. Benefits include -

1. Nice UI to deal with attributes, attribute sets, categories and products.
2. Provides column mapping functionality for CSV.
3. XLS/XLSX files are supported which is a nice touch since a lot of developers use functions to auto fill columns.
4. Connection manager can handle multiple database connections.

There are many more features. Above are just a subset of what I had tried.